# How to delete element from varray in oracle?

Tags: oracle, collections, varray

I create a varray collection as `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE vary_typ IS VARRAY(40) OF NUMBER;
/` and form anonymous block like

```
DECLARE
  v_a vary_typ := vary_typ (1,3,5,6,34,67,50);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN v_a.FIRST..v_a.COUNT
  LOOP
   IF v_a.EXISTS(i) THEN
    v_a.DELETE(i);
   ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
   END IF;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_a);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

But could not delete it.
I know `varray` can't be delete using `.DELETE` method only perform `.TRIM`. But my question, is there any possibility to delete element by convert it into `INDEX BY TABLE` then delete?

I already seen the post [Delete element from Varray Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846221/delete-element-from-varray-oracle). There solution was different what i expected. I want to delete and make varray into sparse collection, can we?